# Computing hash in PHP yields different results on local and test environments.

Tags: javascript, php, hash

I'm trying to server-side validate a hash generated on the client side.

My client-side js code looks like this:

```
_hash: function(value) {
    var hash = 5381;
    for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + value.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return hash;
}
```

and my server-side php code like this:

```
$hash = 5381;
$value = strtoupper($input);
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($value); $i++) {
    $hash = (($hash << 5) + $hash) + ord(substr($value, $i));
}
```

When applied to the string "FMQXXU", you should get -1329107890 on either side.

Both scripts work perfectly on my local environment,
but when i move to test on a different machine, only the js code works. The php code returns 6952222944334.

The local php is version 5.3.8, the 
test php is version 5.3.3.

Why do I get different results?

Comment: Your issue is 32-bit v. 64-bit PHP

Comment: @Baker is there any way workaround?

Comment: @Baker I just check and both systems are 64bit

Comment: 32-bit PHP gives me -1329107890 for "FMQXXU"; 64-bit PHP gives me 6952222944334 for "FMQXXU"; unless your local environment is 64-bit too then should get exactly the results you're getting; if your local environment is 64-bit then you should be getting 6952222944334 there as well

Comment: @Baker yes you are right i checked operating system architecture and it is 64 and php is 32, everything is okay on 32 bit version but in 64 bit php it returns different hash. Do you know about some workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function to convert 64 bits to 32 bits :

```
function to_32bits($val) {
    $sign = 1 << 31;
    return $val & ($sign) ? -(~($val & 0x7fffffff) + 1 + ($sign)) : $val & 0xffffffff;
}
```

Example :

```
$a = -1329107890;
$b = 6952222944334;

function to_32bits($val) {
    $sign = 1 << 31;
    return $val & $sign ? -(~($val & 0x7fffffff) + 1 + $sign) : $val & 0xffffffff;
}

echo $a . ' ' . to_32bits($b);
```

Will output : `-1329107890 -1329107890`

I'm not sure if there is a better way to do the conversion.